# Excel form: Input random date in form comes out all screwy

Tags: forms, date, excel, vba

In excel 2010 I am creating a VERY simple form.  I have a text box in which I ask a user to input a date.  This text box is named startDate

I test it with a date input in the following format:  `dd/mm/yyyy`

then in the VBA editor I declare it as a date:

`Dim startDate As Date`

I next have a message box report back the start date just to make sure its working:
`msgBox (startDate)`

I input `1/12/1983` and the msgBox reports back `12:00 am`

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MsgBox FormatDateTime(TheDate, vbShortDate)
```

---

You can also set the input format like this:

```
Sub inputDate()
    Dim dateString As String, TheDate As Date
    Dim valid As Boolean: valid = True

    Do
      dateString = Application.InputBox("Enter A Start Date (dd/mm/yy): ", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))

      If IsDate(dateString) Then
        TheDate = DateValue(dateString)
        valid = True
      Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date"
        valid = False
      End If
    Loop Until valid = True

    If valid Then MsgBox (TheDate)
End Sub
```